# Terminal not displaying all columns of the table in MySQL

Tags: mysql

under the count column, there is supposed to be integers displayed but instead it is missing. How do i fix this?

[image: example]

i did not alter any settings, when i use

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLES;
```

there was also some alignment issue.

Comment: What is the output of SELECT HEX(count) FROM TABLES? Also some more information, e.g. your table definition and the character sets (database, connection, client) might be helpful.

Comment: The last column contains a Carriage Return character, so it's wrapping around to the beginning of the line and overwriting the count column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `treatment` column apparently ends with a CR character, which is causing the line to wrap to the beginning, and then it overwrites the `count` column. Remove that character when displaying the result:

```
SELECT count, gender, REPLACE(treatment, '\r', '') AS treatment
FROM yourTable
```

It would probably be best to fix how you load the table so it doesn't include that character in the first place. If you're loading from a CSV file, make sure you use `LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'` instead of `LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'`.